# Comparing integrals of bounded subharmonic functions

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, potential-theory

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open open subset. Let $u,v\colon \Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ be two functions such that at least one of them is compactly supported. Assume each of $u$ and $v$ can be presented as a difference of two bounded subharmonic functions in $\Omega$. Thus in particular the distributional Laplacians $\Delta u,\Delta v$ are well defined as signed measures on $\Omega$.

**Question.** Is it true that
$$\int_\Omega u(x)\Delta v(x) dx=\int_\Omega v(x)\Delta u(x) dx?$$

**Remark.** (1) The expressions under the both integrals are well defined as signed measures with compact support. Thus both sides make sense.

(2) The simplest unknown to me case is $n=2$.

Comment: @Christian Remling. You are right. But then it is always true, by approximation: choose shooth $v_n$ converging to $v$ in $D'$.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: I had the same thought, but is it clear: if $v_n\to v$ in $\mathcal D'$, then I only know that $\int u\Delta v_n\to\int u\Delta v$ if $u$ is also smooth.

Comment: It's maybe also possible to reduce this to the $n=1$ case since one can replace $\Omega$ by a rectangle that contains it.

Comment: @Christian Remling: I think justifying the limit in your second comment is a purely technical problem, not very hard. See Landkof, Introduction to modern potential theory, Ch. II, Potentials with finite energy.

Comment: Of course, in general, these integrals can be divergent, so one has to state explicit conditions for them to be finite.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : the integrals converge since one of the functions is compactly supported by assumption.

Comment: Isn't it true that under these conditions, if they are both compactly supported, $u(x)=\int G(x,y)\Delta u(y)dy$, and similarly for $v$? Then, your identity follows by Fubini and the symmetry of Green's function?

Comment: @makt: But $\Delta v$ can have a point mass, while $u$ can be infinite at this point. Moreover, differences of subharmonic functions are in general not everywhere defined: in  $u=u_1-u_2$, both $u_j$ can be $-\infty$ at some point. And $\Delta v$ can have a point mass at this point. So there are problems with definition of these integrals. The probems disappear if you consider "potentials of finite energy" instead of differences of subharmonic functions.

Comment: @Kostya: There are no problems when they are both compactly supported (and both integrals converge).

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : I explicitly stated that both functions are bounded.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko, but if at least one of them is compactly supported (as stated by the OP), can't we modify the other one so that it is also compactly supported without affecting either side of the identity?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko He is explicitly assuming $u$ and $v$ are differences of bounded subharmonic functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without loss of generality, $u$  has compact support $K\subset\Omega$. Therefore the (signed) measure $\Delta u$ is supported in $K$  as well. Let $(\phi_k)$ be a sequence of smooth (radial) mollifiers such that $\phi_k*u$ is supported in $K^\delta$ (the closed $\delta$ neighborhood of $K$, with $\delta>0$ so small that $K^\delta\subset\Omega$). Additionally, suppose $0\le\phi_k$, $\int_{\Bbb R^n}\phi_k(x)\phantom{!}dx=1$, and $\phi_k$ is supported in the ball $B(0,\delta/k)$,  for each $k\ge 1$.
Then $\lim_k \phi_k*u=u$ pointwise and boundedly, because (for example) $u$ is finely continuous. Likewise $\lim_k\phi_k*v=v$. Then
$$
\eqalign{
\int_\Omega u(x)\cdot\Delta v(dx)
&=\lim_k\int_\Omega (\phi_k*u)(x)\cdot\Delta v(dx)\cr
&=\lim_k\int_\Omega \Delta(\phi_k*u)(x)\cdot v(x) \phantom{b}dx\cr
&=\lim_k\int_\Omega (\phi_k*\Delta u)(x)\cdot v(x) \phantom{b}dx\cr
&=\lim_k\int_\Omega (\phi_k*v )(x)\phantom{b}\Delta u(dx)\cr
&=\int_\Omega  v(x)\cdot\Delta u(dx).\cr
}
$$
Here the second equality is just the definition of $\Delta v$ as a distribution; the third likewise; the fourth is Fubini.

(Edited per suggestion of makt, to fix the vacuity noticed by Mateusz Kwaśnicki.)

Comment: The only bounded, subharmonic and compactly supported function is constant zero. :-)

Comment: Good point. Strike the first sentence of my answer (save the stipulation that $u$ be of compact support), and remove "positive" from the second sentence.

Comment: @JohnDawkins : Would you like to edit your answer?